# CoreData: Cascade delete rule only if item all child items deleted

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a one to many relationship A --> B. I want to delete A once all of it's B's have been deleted. I could find a way to do it manually but I'm wondering if there is some way to do it automatically (meaning every time I delete a B, its A object might be deleted depending on the number of Bs it references). I'm wondering if there is some combination of delete rules and relationship cardinality validation to facilitate this. It would be a 'cascade on condition' delete rule.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end I've used prepareForDeletion in B to check whether the associated A only has 1 B (the one being deleted). If so I delete the A as well.
Found the answer here:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326979/using-cascade-delete-rule-and-validatefordelete-on-a-one-to-many-relationship-in)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are only four types of delete rules in core data, none of which meets your requirement.